# Cakephp, Interrelated radio buttons?

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, radio-button

my issue here is how to relate radio buttons in a table where is made by a foreach, please take a look on my view.

```
                            <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>Destaque</th>
                                    <th>Remover</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                <?php $a=0;

                foreach ($Lotesimagem as $l): 

                        if($a==0){$a=1;
                            ?>
                                <tr>
                        <?php }else{?>
                                <tr class="alt">
                        <?php $a=0;}?>   

                                    <td><?php echo $l['Lotesimagem']['nome']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $l['Lotesimagem']['destaque']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link('Remover', '/Vendedores/view'); ?></td>
                                </tr>

       <?php endforeach; ?>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

where `<?php echo $l['Lotesimagem']['destaque']; ?>` should be a radio button. It is suppose that in that table only one radio button could have one value true the others must be false. When i click on other button it changes to true and others to false, and so on.
Notice that the main problem here is not how to make a radio button but most of all how to interconnect them in a table that is being created with  a loop.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To relate radio buttons, you need to put the same `name` property for each group. For other groups, you need to put other names.

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female

<input type="radio" name="sex1" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex1" value="female">Female
```

Look at the name property... if you change it, you relate it to group you need.

look to the generated html on the view, and you will find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to display it as radio buttons:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('Lotesimagem.nome', array(
       'options' => array(1=>'Male', 0=>'Female')
 ));
```

If somehow you want to update those fields as the radio button you must use AJAX to do it, or you can create form with the radio buttons as its input and submit it for updates in database. You can then debug in your controller to see if the radio buttons are connected to the values you have chosen in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are trying to add radio button in view page it is looking odd.However it is possible.You can try by this line.

```
<td><input type="radio"><?php echo $l['Lotesimagem']['destaque']; ?></td>
```